# Insertion in Hash Table using Singly Linked Lists

Tags: c++, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I'm new here, I need some help with this problem, the problem is that it stores value for the first entry, but when I'm creating a list, for example when I want to insert `22`, after I have inserted `2` before, it behaves as if it added the node after `2`, but actually it doesn't create and I don't know why. Need assistance on this one, please.

```
 void insertKey(int key) {

        int i = Hash(key);
        Node* temp = HashTable[i];

        Node* NewNode = new Node;
        NewNode->key = key;
        NewNode->next = NULL;
        if (temp == NULL) {
            HashTable[i] = NewNode;
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp != NULL) {
                cout << "NOTHere ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp == NULL) {
                cout << "FoundYa ";
                temp = NewNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you assign `temp = NewNode` you're not actually setting the value of the previous `temp->next` to `NewNode`. You don't need to set `temp` to `NewNode`, you need to set `temp->next` to `NewNode` once `temp->next == NULL`.

Comment: Sir, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: I need to understand this (temp->next) logic and why doesn't it work with the above logic that I used, can you please help me understand better?

Comment: @ShaharyarKhan The preferred way to indicate that a question is solved is to accept the answer that solved it, not to edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `temp = NewNode;` you're not actually setting the value of the previous `temp->next` to `NewNode`. You don't need to set `temp` to `NewNode`, you need to set `temp->next` to `NewNode` once `temp->next == NULL`.

What you are currently doing is this:

```
[ node 1 ] --> nullptr
                 |
                 |
        assign nullptr to temp
                 |
                 V
                temp <--- then assign NewNode to temp
```

What you need to do is this:

```
[ node 1 ] --> nullptr
    |
    |
  assign this to temp
    |
    V
   temp --> nullptr <-- assign NewNode to this
```

Comment: Couldn't be more clear sir, thank you so much, I appreciate your help.